# jQuery and datepicker

Tags: jquery, calendar

im having a hard time finding a good date picker for my web. im trying to create a dynamic date picker that pops from a textbox on click allowing me to choose Year, Month and day in the month in the same screen. when i find some datepicker like tigara there is no explanation how to use. it will be nice if u give me calendar and what code should i write in order to make it work. including HTML, Jquery function and css included. p.s im a jQuery newbie , so have merci

Comment: Where's the effort? What's wrong with the official jQuery UI datepicker?

Comment: Have a look at the datepicker included in [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: problem is that nothing happens when i press on the text box...
added the scripts srcs...and wrote 1 short func i saw in source page after i add the files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Very easy to implement and great documentation/examples.

Comment: problem is that nothing happens when i press on the text box...
added the scripts srcs...and wrote 1 short func i saw in source page after i add the files...

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael well it works for everyone else so probably you did something wrong. If you use chrome hit ctrl+shift+J to open the console and look for error messages.

Comment: now it works..but i cant see the Css of it..

Comment: You should have a css file that came with datepicker. Just put it in yoru path and link it like anyother css files.

Comment: Cool! Happy to have been of help thanks for the points :-)

Comment: u know about Time chosing? same like this calander or maybe some drop down list on time? with like 15 min jumping or customized?

Comment: @OriGavrielRefael pretty sure there is a datetimepicker on jquery somewhere. Search for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Is well documented

Answer (score 0):

At http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ there are a bunch of examples.  Notice that if you click "View Source" you can see how each is implemented.

That's how I was able to figure out how to use it (also as a jQuery newbie).

When it's time to customize, also pay attention to the documentation at the aforementioned site; the various options are detailed.